# Put-call parity and different IVs for puts and calls

Tags: implied-volatility, put-call-parity

For vanilla options put-call parity
$$
C - P = F
$$
must hold. On the other hand, it can happen that puts can have different implied vols than calls, due to for example shorting restrictions, borrowing costs, or if the underlying is not traded.

My interpretation would be that a long call and short put must have the same IV, and a short call and long put must have the same IV as  well, but not necessarily a long call and long put, or short call and short put.

Does this make sense? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: What you refer to as "the price of a long call" I would refer to as the "ask price of a call", similarly I would  refer to the "bid price of a put". So what you are saying is testing the PCP should take into account bid ask spreads. Which I would agree with.

Comment: @nbbo2 Well I don't know, because the ask IV of a call should (according to my reasoning) be different than the ask IV of a put, whereas usually the ask IV is the ask IV. So according to what I wrote the ask IV of a call should be the bid IV of a put. This is weird, but PCP should hold, and $C -  P$ means long call short put..

Comment: Does writing $F=C-P$ imply that there are no major shorting restrictions because you can be short the put? So, the difference in IVs in your example would be attributable to the bid-ask spread, not shorting restrictions? P.S. Nice to have you back!

Comment: @Kevin Thanks Kevin. I think, since the payoff of the forward contract can always be settled in cash, the PCP condition can always be written down as long as the price of the underlying is observable. I've been out of the market for so long now that I don't know what practical situations can arise exactly. So basically lacking relevant data.